# ReactJS: render doesn't change the style value based on props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We're building a wordpress builder on ReactJS and encountered a weird looking problem. 
In the 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEbFe.png) you can see a `wrapperStyle` object with some CSS styling.The styling should change based on `this.props`. When `this.props` changes, the `console.log` for this object returns

> this.props.fullSlideshowWidth = 1920px

and

> this.props.slideshowWidth = 1400px

I expected the style attribute in DOM to change it's value too, however it doesn't change.

For example if I access a full width slideshow page, the style attribute will have `max-width: 1920px`. If I access a different page with a normal slideshow the style attribute will remain the same, although the value in `console.log` will change.

Comment: It looks like you are setting a width value based on the existence of a *height* variable. Is `this.props.slideshowFullHeight` getting set? If you run a `console.log(wrapperStyle)` right before the return statement, does it show all of the correctly changed values?

Comment: Hello Andy,

Thanks for the answer. Yes, if I run a console.log the values are shown correctly.  `this.props.slideshowFullHeight` only checks if the slideshow settings are set to Full Width or not, from this option: http://i.imgur.com/EzQ41SH.jpg

Comment: And you are positive that `render()` is being called again every time the props change? What you are doing is totally valid - building out a style object with properties that change depending on props/state is a fairly normal thing. I wonder if there is some greater issue with your Flux implementation that is suppressing new `render()` calls after a props change?

Comment: I just made a small screen recording to show you the problem in real-time.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qd6bt3kFcnc

Comment: I think that this.props.slideshowFullHeight is always interpreted as true, because is not an empty string there for the this.props.fullSlideshowWidth is assigned no matter what.

Comment: Nope, `this.props.slideshowFullHeight` returns true when I access a page with full height slideshow and false when access a page with normal slideshow.

Comment: After watching your video, I see that you are using `calc()` for a different height CSS property. I am not sure if React correctly processes that. If one of your CSS properties is invalid in a render, React will disregard the whole thing for that render. Can you comment out the other 2 CSS properties from that object so that you only have the width left and see if that changes things?

Comment: @AndyNoelker Yes, I'm using calc(), React processes it pretty good, as we used it in other components, also I just commented the other CSS styles and the problem still persists, the values change in `console.log` and do not change in the inline styling.

Comment: Yeah I thought it probably would be fine as by that point React is just blindly passing that value to the browser, but I figured it would be worth a shot. Honestly this is very confusing. If that style object is changing during a render, it should update with the new style. I just ran a test myself with a similar setup (only the object got its properties from local state) and it worked fine. I was able to toggle styles with a button and the properties worked. This is truly bizarre.

Comment: So I just noticed in your video that you are filtering out all errors and warnings in your console. Is there anything helpful in there? Maybe even something that looks unrelated is somehow affecting this, because the basic logic that you are implementing is correct. I'm not sure if something in your slides was breaking that would cause all of the JSX for its parent components to stop rendering, but it's possible.

Comment: @AndyNoelker nope, the warnings are regarding to "each child in an array should have a unique key prop", I will fix those warnings later on.

The issue is pretty interesting, we tried today in office for a couple of hours to change this style, make it as a state, change it;s value... and nothing works. I really want to understand what's going wrong here, it's interesting :)

Comment: It really is extremely strange. I don't understand but I still suspect it is something weird with how your Flux implementation or slides are affecting rendering, as your basic logic is sound. Check this fiddle I just created that implements the most basic form of your style logic and it works just fine https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/28815/

Comment: @AndyNoelker I was thinking about that but since the render and the console show me the correct value of the maxWidth I think the Flux implementation is correct.

Comment: @AndyNoelker I solved it, I posted the answer below, thanks though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys who tried to help me, I solved the issue by editing the props: 
 `slideshowWidth = {this.state.settings.images.sizes.slideshow.width+'px !important'}` 
I just removed `!important` out of it and works without a problem, I still do not understand why `!important` had such a big influence on the prop.

Answer (score 0):

You might try;

```js
var wrapperStyle = {};
wrapperStyle.marginBottom = this.getFlux()...;
wrapperStyle.maxWidth = this.props...;
wrapperSytle.height = this.props...;
```

Comment: That didn't change much, the issue still persists.

Comment: In that case; is maxWidth mutable?

Comment: maxWidth is css "max-width" and is mutable, I really don't know what causes the problem